# My functions are either not declared properly or in the right place, "use strict".

Tags: javascript, function, jslint

I've been using JSLint on my code, and this part of my code I just can't figure out... JSLint gives me the following message:

Function statements should not be placed in blocks.Use a function expression or move the statement to the top of the outer function.

and thit message implies to the following functions:

function callbackRed() {

AND

function callMIDRed() {

I've tried assigning them to variables, and putting them even in variables at the top of the function(turnEvent)... but it just looks uglier and it doesn't work when I tried it...(maybe I'm calling the code wrong).

```
function turnEvent(x, y) {
    "use strict";
    var kassi = collides(rects, x, y);
    if (kassi) {
        context.fillStyle = "White";
        context.fillRect(kassi.x, kassi.y, 90, 110);
        function callbackRed() {
            setTimeout(function returnSizeRed() {
                context.fillStyle = kassi.color;
                context.fillRect(kassi.x, kassi.y, 90, 110);
            }, 50);
        }
        function callMIDRed() {
            setTimeout(function displayMidRed() {
                context.fillStyle = kassi.color;
                context.fillRect(kassi.x + 12, kassi.y + 12, 60, 80);
                return callbackRed();
            }, 50);
        }
        setTimeout(function displayRectRed() {
            context.fillStyle = kassi.color;
            context.fillRect(kassi.x + 35, kassi.y + 35, 20, 40);
            return callMIDRed();
        }, 50);
    }
}//turnEvent();
```

Comment: Give it a spanking and send it to bed without dinner. (Also, take them out of the `if` block.)

Comment: The question I think many will have for you is, "*Why* are you declaring functions *inside* one?"

Comment: @esqew what else is there to use? I am able to call 4 lines of particular code and run these 3 function in a specific order.

Comment: @JaredFarrish is the if entirely useless? That's what I'm thinking right now.

Comment: I have no idea. Take the functions out of the `if` block. Voila, strict. `if` has no scope, so it matters not if they are in or outside of the `if` for execution.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Give that man a cookie! :D... Thank you, helped me a lot :)

Comment: `@esqew`, it's fine to put functions inside of each other in JavaScript. Not sure why you got points.

Comment: @GuðniMárGilbert : by the way, please rename your question to be a bit more precise.

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck Will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block in question is your `if`block.

Because of something that's called [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), it is discouraged to declare a variable in an `if` block (or `for`, or `while`, or `else` for that matter), because it can make you think that you're variable is only visible in that block, and it's wrong. As it happens, one of the consequences of a function statement is to declare a variable.

The solution in your situation is to move these function declarations outside of that `if` block :

```
function turnEvent(x, y) {
  "use strict";
  var kassi = collides(rects, x, y);
  function callbackRed() {
    setTimeout(function returnSizeRed() {
      context.fillStyle = kassi.color;
      context.fillRect(kassi.x, kassi.y, 90, 110);
    }, 50);
  }
  function callMIDRed() {
    setTimeout(function displayMidRed() {
      context.fillStyle = kassi.color;
      context.fillRect(kassi.x + 12, kassi.y + 12, 60, 80);
      return callbackRed();
    }, 50);
  }

  if (kassi) {
    context.fillStyle = "White";
    context.fillRect(kassi.x, kassi.y, 90, 110);
    setTimeout(function displayRectRed() {
      context.fillStyle = kassi.color;
      context.fillRect(kassi.x + 35, kassi.y + 35, 20, 40);
      return callMIDRed();
    }, 50);
  }
}//turnEvent();
```

Comment: Your reasoning regarding why function statements should be avoided is incorrect. Function statements are an extension to the specification and are only supported in a few browsers. As a result, using them gives different results in different browsers. See [*Named function expressions demystified: function expressions*](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#function-statements).

Comment: I've read your link and I don't see how that makes the reasoning incorrect, to me it only adds to it, can you elaborate please?

Comment: Because not using function statements is not about "hoisting", it's about different results in different browsers. In Firefox, *callbackRed* and *callMIDRed* are conditionally created.

Comment: I agree that's an issue, but apparently that's not the issue JSlint is complaining about : "Function statements should not be placed in blocks.Use a function expression or move the statement to the top of the outer function.". Don't tell me, tell JSlint :)

Comment: It's being in a block that makes it a function statement in Firefox (but not in other browsers). Taking it out of the block makes it a function declaration in all browsers. JSLint is saying "*don't use function statements, use declarations or expressions*", which is good advice.

Answer (score 0):

The reason not to use function statements is that they are only supported by a few browsers and lead to very different results in different browsers.

Under the topic [*Function Definition*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13) ECMA-262 defines *FunctionDeclaration* and *FunctionExpression*. A *function statement* is an extension to the language introduced by Mozilla and not supported by all browsers. Function statements appear to be function declarations in browsers that don't support statements, for example:

```
if (true) {
  function foo() {alert('foo')}
} else {
  function foo() {alert('Not foo')}    
}
```

In the above, a browser that does not support *function statements* (e.g. IE, Safari) will see two function declarations, with the second replacing the first, before any code is run. So:

```
foo() // Not foo
```

However, in a browser that supports function statements (e.g. Firefox), the function is conditionally created and:

```
foo() // foo
```

You'll find much more detail in Kangax's article on [*Named function expressions demystified: Function statements*](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#function-statements).